# fatal: The current branch NOMBRERAMA has no upstream branch

Tags: git, git-push

Estoy haciendo un juego y corregí unos bugs en una rama que cree especialmente para ello llamada "FixBugs", hice un commit en dicha rama cuando ya los conseguí corregir. Pero me encuentro el siguiente mensaje cuando quiero hacer el push:

> fatal: The current branch FixBugs has no upstream branch

¿Qué quiere decir esto?

Comment: puedes agregar la linea del git push , no coloques los datos importantes por favor

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Significa que la rama existe en local (donde la has creado), pero que no existe en remoto.

Debería funcionarte si la defines explícitamente para crearla:

```
git push -u origin FixBugs
```